# JavaScript link preview for touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some JavaScript on a website I'm currently making which causes selected links to show a preview when moused over which works fine, however for touch devices when the links are tapped it shows the preview then sends the user to the site, I'd like it to show just the preview on the first tap, then if they tap again to send them to the page.

How can I do this?

My Java Script that I've used:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://codegena.com/assets/css/image-preview-for-link.css" rel="stylesheet">     
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
            $('#p1 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'pageload' });
            $('#p2 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'parenthover' });
            $('#p3 a').miniPreview({ prefetch: 'none' });
        });
```

And the HTML:

```
<p id="p1" align="center"><a href="http://link">link description</a><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>
<p id="p2" align="center"><a href="http://link">link description</a><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>
<p id="p3" align="center"><a href="http://link">link description</a><br><br><br><br></p>
```

Comment: A tap is a click. If you don't want the first tap to work, you would disable the native functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that would prevent the first click from sending you to the page but the second click does.

```
var click = 0;
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
var clickNum = ++click;
if(clickNum == 1) {
   event.preventDefault();
   //preview code
} 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, only just started using javascript, what should the final code look like?

Comment: Do you already have the code for the preview of the next page? If you do remove the `//preview code` and add the code you made.